# Could not find function "dinvgauss"

Tags: r

I am currently writing an R program where I am using the inverse Gaussian distribution. However, when attempting to use it I get the following error:

> Error in dinvgauss(xfit, result.mean, lambda = lambda) :    could not
>   find function "dinvgauss"

Other distributions work (i.e the gamma and exponential). Any ideas what the problem is and how I could attempt to mitigate it?

Comment: I have found that function in two packages, `STAR` and `ActuDistns`. Tip: install package `sos` and then `sos::findFn("dinvgauss")`. It's a great package.

Comment: Thanks @Rui! This newbie will give that a try

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the package and install it. It seems `STAR` package contains the function, but not sure if it is the same you are looking for:

```
install.packages("STAR", dependencies =T )
library("STAR")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical "missing dependency" issue. The package [rmutil](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rmutil/html/00Index.html) provides a bunch of special functions used in statistical analysis (pdf, cdfs, quantiles,...). To solve the problem in question, just do

```
library(rmutil)
```

and then you can run statistical analysis on top, for instance

```
library(fitdistrplus)
X = c(24, 24, 26, 26, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 35, 41, 42, 43, 47, 48, 48, 48, 50, 52, 54, 55, 57, 57, 57, 57, 61)
fig <- fitdist(X, "invgauss", ...)
```